# Show image in angularjs-gridster cell

Tags: angularjs, image, angularjs-gridster

[here is the snapshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WosG.png) I am facing issues while adding an image in a gridster cell. I am using AngularJS v1.5.x.

***css of gridster***

```
.showImage {
  display: block;
  background: url("../assets1/images/avatars/profile.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

***HTML of gridster***

```
    <div class="columns" ng-style="{height: $ctrl.columnsHeight + 'px'}">
  <div class="column showImage" ng-repeat="column in $ctrl.columns"
       ng-style="{'min-width': $ctrl.width + 'px', 'margin-left': ($first && !$ctrl.gridster.$options.outerMargin ? 0 : $ctrl.margin) + 'px'}">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="rows" ng-style="{width: $ctrl.rowsWidth + 'px'}">
  <div class="row showImage" ng-repeat="row in $ctrl.rows"
       ng-style="{height: $ctrl.height + 'px', 'margin-top': ($first && !$ctrl.gridster.$options.outerMargin ? 0 :$ctrl.margin) + 'px'}">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post your source code!

Comment: I have updated the post you can check.

Comment: what's the problem that you are having? Post some sceenshots of what you're seeing and what you want it to look.

Comment: @Axr Please check the post i have updated it with screenshot.

Comment: Anyone who can help ?